# i have some trouble in typecasting

Tags: c, arrays, printf, minesweeper

i am working in a university project that i should write a minesweaper game with some array ...
i have written my program 
the program will print the minesweaper table some cell in the table has bomb the program should print `*` in that cell.
and other cell should print number of bomb in eight surrounding cell 
I don't know how to print this double sub-scripted array that can print character and number both.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define max 100
int  main()
{
    int a,row,column,n,x,y,counter,i,j;
    char table[max][max]={0};
    scanf("%d%d",&row,&column);
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);
        table[x-1][y-1]='*';
    }
    for(counter=0,i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
            for(j=0;j<column;j++)
        {
            if(table[i-1][j-1]=='*')
            counter++;
            if(table[i-1][j]=='*')
            counter++;
            if(table[i-1][j+1]=='*')
            counter++;
            if(table[i][j-1]=='*')
            counter++;
            if(table[i][j+1]=='*')
            counter++;
            if(table[i+1][j-1]=='*')
            counter++;
            if(table[i+1][j]=='*')
            counter++;
            if(table[i+1][j+1]=='*')
            counter++;
            if(table[i][j]!='*')
            table[i][j]=counter;
            counter=0;
        }
    }
for(counter=0,i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
            for(j=0;j<column;j++)   
            printf("%d ",(char)table[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no **typecasting** in programming!

Comment: Change printf("%d ",(char)table[i][j]); to printf("%c ",(char)table[i][j]); and you will see your character.

Comment: Use `"%c"` instead of `"%d"` in your `printf`. Typecasting is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but your code will not work because

```
    if(table[i][j]!='*')
    table[i][j]=counter;
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Will overwrite what is in the location at i,j and the later passes will not see a '*' there. So basically your counts are going to be all messed up. You need one array for the '*' and another for the neighbor counts.